# Accessing files in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am developing an application in iOS 4.0, after having made several apps in Symbian S60v3.
Where I am stuck in iOS is that I want to access a file from the device which is saved from a third-party application to some location on the device.

In the case of symbian I knew its location: `System\Data\xyz\alpha.inf`, but with iOS I don't know how to access the location.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. It is one of the security features in iOS that applications are sandboxed and cannot share data at all.

Comment: okey, but just to clear the third party downloads the file from safari, as i click on the link the safari opens up and somehow downloads the file and trigers the third party application, there would be some location where the file is saved, and can i open that file from my application? i just want to trigger that file to be opend in the respective application , but on a button click on my app.